# how to extract a specified url parameter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello I have a specified URL `https://www.example.com/doctor`

I want to extract the parameter doctor from the URL so that I can compare that the URL has a doctor in it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Laravel's Routing docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing

Something like this to retrieve "doctor" out of your example url:

```
Route::get('{$item}', function ($item) {
    return $item; // https://www.example.com/doctor => "doctor"
});
```